# reverse accessor model clashing Django Web App

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, backend

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class Customer(AbstractUser):
    address_line = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    origin_country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='customer_profile_pics', null=True, blank=True)


class Chef(AbstractUser):
    address_line = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    origin_country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='chef_profile_pics', null=True, blank=True)


class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='meal_pics')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    chef = models.ForeignKey(Chef, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='meals')
    customers = models.ManyToManyField(Customer, blank=True, related_name='meals')


class Discussion(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='discussions')
    chef = models.ForeignKey(Chef, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='discussions')
```

This is my `models.py` file
I get the following error while making migrations

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
meals.Chef.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Chef.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Customer.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Chef.groups' or 'Customer.groups'.
meals.Chef.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Chef.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Customer.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Chef.user_permissions' or 'Customer.user_permissions'.
meals.Customer.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Customer.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Chef.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Customer.groups' or 'Chef.groups'.
meals.Customer.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Customer.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Chef.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Customer.user_permissions' or 'Chef.user_permissions'.
```

I tried some solutions on the internet but it didn't work, i want to test the app on my browser but making the migrations keeps showing me this error, please help!!!!

I am really new to Django Back End Dev, I tried to troubleshoot the issue but i couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why create two User models ? With same field ?
`AbstractUser` is for defining your custom model used for authentication. Are you sure you have understood that ?

For resolving your case, you have to override `user_permissions` and `groups` from Abstract user for redefine related_name of this fields...

```py
class Chef(...):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        related_name="XXXXX",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        related_name="YYYYY",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
```

Comment: how do i do that sir how do i override them ?

Comment: I edited my question, but maybe can you read some documentation about OOP I think ? https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/